# Using filters with a list in R with Google Analytics package

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to extract a specific set of productskus from Google Analtics with several metrics included. My set of sku that I would like to extract are in a list. I cannot seem to get Analytics to do what I need it to do.

I have been trying to see how to filter on a list. The most common answer that I am able to find on how to use the dim_filter is from this website:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googleAnalyticsR/versions/0.7.0/topics/dim_filter

I have tried multiple ways to get my answer and am always getting errors at many different parts of the code.

```
stDate <- "2019-07-18"
endDate <- "2019-09-30"

x <- list(BC$sku)


#Get all of the info from Analytics for products
b <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
       date_range = c(stDate, endDate),
       metrics = c("itemQuantity", "itemRevenue", "productDetailViews"),
       dimensions = c("productSku"),
       dim_filter = x,
       anti_sample = TRUE)
```

The above code gives me the following error:

Error in as(dim_filters, ".filter_clauses_ga4") : 
  no method or default for coercing “list” to “.filter_clauses_ga4”

I am not able to get any output from this code as the filter is not working.

I can of course, query the entire dataset, but that becomes cumbersome very fast as I would like to be able to query the Google Analytics API with a specific set of skus anytime that I would like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct your filter object more to handle the list of SKUs.  As specified in the [official googleAnalyticsR documentation](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/v4.html#filters) `dim_filters` are created with the `dim_filter()` function and `filter_clause_ga4()`

You can send a list of `dim_filter()` in, or try use the "IN_LIST" operator and send in your character vector (if its not too big)

In the latter case the final code would look something like:

```r
stDate <- "2019-07-18"
endDate <- "2019-09-30"



# if small enough list
dim_filters <- list(dim_filter("product_sku", "IN_LIST", BC$sku))


#Get all of the info from Analytics for products
b <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
       date_range = c(stDate, endDate),
       metrics = c("itemQuantity", "itemRevenue", "productDetailViews"),
       dimensions = c("productSku"),
       dim_filter = filter_clause_ga4(dim_filters),
       anti_sample = TRUE)


# this may work as well to construct the filter
dim_filters <- lapply(BC$sku, 
    function(x) {
      dim_filter("product_sku" ,operator = "EXACT", expressions = x)
    })
```